# How to publish a collection based on a value of an array value

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have the following data structure in a Meteor app, I would like to create a publication based on the "modelo" value.

```
{
  "_id": "BAnLur25298ytvMdT",
  "numero": "97",
  "lienzos": 100,
  "fechaCorte": "2016-03-29T00:00:00.000Z",
  "modelos": [
    {
      "modelo": "95",
      "distribucion": 100
    },
    {
      "modelo": "96",
      "distribucion": 100
    }
  ],
  "tela": "Jackard"
}
```

For example :

```
Meteor.publish('ModelosCorte', function(id) {
  return CortesGeneral.find({
    modelos: id
  });
});
```

But I want to publish for example all CortesGeneral that have a "modelo": "96" as a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use dot notation to specify that you want to search for `'modelos.modelo'`. Give this a try:

```js
Meteor.publish('ModelosCorte', function (id) {
  check(id, String);
  return CortesGeneral.find({ 'modelos.modelo': id });
});
```